# Identifying time complexity for a loop

Tags: c, while-loop, time-complexity

I was hoping to have some help in identifying the time complexity of the while loop below. I am trying to solve a problem in o(n) time complexity and was unsure whether this loop would satisfy this condition.

If the loop is not o(n) time complexity would it be o(n^2)?

Thank you :)

```
int a = 0;
int b = a + 1;
while (a < n) {
    b++;
    if (b == n) {
        a++;
        b = a + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like O(n) to me

Comment: @pVCaecidiosporeadduced, note that `a` is incremented only per o(n)-th iteration, o(n^2) is a viable hypothesis

Comment: The total number of iterations is `(n - b) + (n - b - 1) + ... + 1` which makes the complexity `O(n²)`.

Comment: Actually it should be `b = a;` in your if statement.  Otherwise the program does not terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume here that the assignment in the `if` branch is `b = a;` instead of `b = a + 1;`, otherwise, there is an infinite loop.)

Your algorithm generates all the couples `(a, b)` such that `a < n`, `b < n` and `b > a`.  There are exactly `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1` couples that satisfy this constraint.  `(n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1 = (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2` which gives a complexity in `O(n²)`.

You might be mislead by the fact that there is a single loop in your program which might give the impression that the complexity is `O(n)`, but your algorithm can be rewritten as follows:

```
int a = 0;
int b;
while (a < n) {
    b = a + 1;
    while (b < n) {
       b ++;
    }
    a++;
}
```

This makes it easier to see that the complexity is indeed `O(n²)`.

Comment: It should be `a,b < n`, not `a + b < n`

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop for all values of `n` in range `[1, infinity)` because when `a++` will result in value of `a` equal to `n - 1`, the value of `b` will reset to `a + 1`  , which is nothing but `n` *[`a + 1` => `n - 1 + 1` => `n`]* and in next iteration `b` will be incremented by `1` and then, theoretically, `b == n` will never be `true`.

> *I am trying to solve a problem in o(n) time complexity....*

It would be better if you share some details about the algorithm that you are trying to implement to solve the problem.